# JOI - how to require at least one field from a set of fields

Tags: node.js, joi

Lets say I have a list of fields like this:

```
Joi.object().keys({
        a: Joi.string(),
        b: Joi.string(),
        c: Joi.string(),
    });
```

I want at least one of the keys be present and have a not null value. How Can I do that?

Comment: Please refer this link it will help you with that https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1141

Answer (score 0):

Please refer
[Question: how to require at least one field from a set of optative fields](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1141)

Comment: please provide a clear answer, rather than just a link.